# Pandas DF. Mapping values to new column, but different rows. DF has multindex

Tags: python, pandas

I am working with a large DataFrame with a 2 column unnamed multindex similar to the df below. I want to add a new column to the df that reflects the next day's close. The dates have gaps for weekends and holidays.

```
                                                50_SMA    close  
2016-01-07 00:00:00+00:00 Equity(24 [AAPL]  115.063406   105.23   
                          Equity(31 [ABAX]   52.092662    55.69   
                          Equity(41 [ARCB]   23.998613    21.38   

                                                 50_SMA    close  
2016-01-08 00:00:00+00:00 Equity(24 [AAPL])  114.904503   105.33   
                          Equity(31 [ABAX])   52.304278    54.38   
                          Equity(41 [ARCB])   23.861307    20.87

                                                 50_SMA    close  
2016-01-11 00:00:00+00:00 Equity(24 [AAPL])  114.658547   105.85   
                          Equity(31 [ABAX])   52.564221    55.02   
                          Equity(41 [ARCB])   23.736181    21.14
```

What I want is ...

```
                                                50_SMA    close   next_days_close
2016-01-07 00:00:00+00:00 Equity(24 [AAPL]  115.063406   105.23   105.33
                          Equity(31 [ABAX]   52.092662    55.69   54.38
                          Equity(41 [ARCB]   23.998613    21.38   20.87

                                                 50_SMA    close  next_days_close
2016-01-08 00:00:00+00:00 Equity(24 [AAPL])  114.904503   105.33  105.85
                          Equity(31 [ABAX])   52.304278    54.38  55.02
                          Equity(41 [ARCB])   23.861307    20.87  21.14

                                                 50_SMA    close  next_days_close
2016-01-11 00:00:00+00:00 Equity(24 [AAPL])  114.658547   105.85   
                          Equity(31 [ABAX])   52.564221    55.02   
                          Equity(41 [ARCB])   23.736181    21.14
```

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try **.shift(-1)** ? This is to shift a column one row up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `groupby/shift` to shift rows *within each group*:

```
df['next_days_close'] = df.groupby(level=1)['close'].shift(-1)
```

---

For example,

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
np.random.seed([2,718])
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['X','Y','Z'], [1,2,3]])
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(9,2)), columns=list('AB'), index=index)
df['C'] = df.groupby(level=1)['B'].shift(-1)
print(df)
```

prints

```
     A  B    C
X 1  6  5  6.0
  2  1  8  9.0
  3  4  4  3.0
Y 1  9  6  7.0
  2  7  9  7.0
  3  4  3  5.0
Z 1  7  7  NaN
  2  4  7  NaN
  3  3  5  NaN
```

Comment: Absolutely perfect. Thank you SO much.